# "Android Studio 3.1.2" error de conexion jdbc y mysql

Tags: android-studio, jdbc, mysqlconnector.jar

Ya he "escudriñado" esta web en busca de la solución al problema de la conexión con MySql mediante jdbc y veo que algunos usuarios lo han conseguido, sin el Webservice.

El mensaje de error que me indica es:

> Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/mysql/jdbc/Driver

Mi código no es muy diferente del que ya he visto en otras preguntas... y utilizo la libreria mysql-connector-java-8.0.11, que no sé si estara bien insertada(?)

```
package com.example.proyectojd.login.login;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText etUsuario;
    private EditText etContrasena;
    private String bd = "autos-control";
    private String sv = "192.168.1.3";
    private String pt = "3306";
    private String us = "root";
    private String ct = "";
    private Button btAceptar;
    private TextView tvMensaje;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btAceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (conectarMySQL()==true) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Conexion establecida.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Conexion NO establecida.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    public boolean conectarMySQL ()
    {
        boolean estadoConexion = false;
        Connection conexionMySQL = null;

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String urlMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://" + sv + ":" + pt + "/";
        Toast.makeText(this,urlMySQL + bd + " " + us+ " " + ct,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conexionMySQL = DriverManager.getConnection(urlMySQL + bd ,us,ct);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error al comprobar las credenciales:" + ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error:" + ex.getCause(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Agradeceria un poco de ayuda. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una pregunta que para mí sería determinante: ¿**dónde está la base de datos**, en el servidor? Si es así, ¿no te parece una idea totalmente descabellada trasladar el driver de conexión a Android y manejar la conexión desde la app, cuando esos procedimientos ya pueden existir de forma segura y fácil en el servidor? Por el contrario, si lo que quieres es usar una BD localmente en la app, se recomienda usar `SQLite`.

Comment: Gracias por la rapida respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la rapida respuesta. Si, la bb.dd. esta en el servidor. Lo que me gustaria es conectarme a mi servidor mysql para ver mis bases de datos, estilo "RemoDB SQL" o "MySQL Client" y de ahi, hacer mis propias pantallas.. Ademas, no tengo XAMPP, tengo un ASP.net.

Comment: Si la BD está en el servidor entonces queda claro que lo mejor sería programar un Servicio Web (en el servidor), que sea el que se conecte a la base de datos. No veo la necesidad de complicarse relegando la conexión **al lado contrario**. Sólo por citar algunas desventajas: tienes que meter los drivers JDBC en tu App (más uso de espacio); tienes que permitir que desde la App misma se conecte a la BD (seguridad, y tendrás que establecer controles muy serios sobre el tipo de consultas que se pueden hacer, etc);  tus credenciales de conexión estarán yendo y viniendo constantemente entre la ...

Comment: ...App y el servidor (seguridad vulnerada); ninguna utilidad desde el punto de vista práctico o lógico, puesto que de todos modos tendrás que consultar al servidor, buscar los datos allí y devolverlos a la App... ¿por qué entonces no conectarte a la BD allí donde ella está? Además, con unas pocas líneas de código podrás crear tu propio Web Service, y hacer peticiones a través de puntos de entrada, como funcionan las API modernas: `dominio.com/usuarios/id/1` Ahí, x ejemplo, por medio de redirecciones, consultaras los datos del usuario con id 1 en la BD.

Answer (score -2):

En cuanto a el error:

> Error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/mysql/jdbc/Driver

No estas registrando el .jar correctamente en tu proyecto, puedes agregar el .jar en Android 3.0 o posterior, lo correcto sería ir a:

`File`  > `New`  > `New Module`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona `Import .JAR/.AAR Package` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí seleccionas la ubicación de tu archivo .jar y se agregará y registrará en tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias, asi lo he hecho y continua con el mismo error

Comment: Gracias, asi lo he hecho pero continua con el mismo error y la apariencia de la ventana de la izquierda, es la misma que antes.